# Programming in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I recently started programming in Prolog.
And it's so confusing.

I am supposed to make an application that asks for the name of the user and the year that the user was born, and prints the name and the AGE of the user.

My question is, how do we use sub method on the main methods? Here it is my code:

```
information:-
    write('Enter your name'),
    read(A),
    write('Enter your year of birth'),nl,
    read(B),
    subt(X,B,Y):- Y is (2011)-B,nl,
    asserta(A,Y),nl,
    write('%w%w%w%w','Your name is', A , ' and your age is ', Y).
```

Comment: Words like _method_ is meaningless in Prolog. Think about predicates and clauses. If you are completly new to Prolog, read some tutorials, ex. [Prolog Tutorial](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html) or [A Short tutorial on Prolog](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/)

Answer (score 0):

**Sample**

```
information :-
    write('Enter your name'),nl,
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Name),
    write('Enter your year of birth'),nl,
    read(BirthYear),
%   subt(BirthYear,Age),
    plus(Age,BirthYear,2011),
    format('~s~s~s~d~n',['Your name is ', Name , ' and your age is ', Age]). 


subt(B,Y) :- Y is 2011 - B.
```